Question closed as an offtopic
This question: Is there a quantitative finance ranking system for universities? was closed as an off-topic. While reading articles What kind of questions can I ask here? and What kind of questions should I not ask here? I haven't find a reason for my question to be closed.
To clarify the situation: that is not the question about your favorite quant school. That is just a call for the reference what are the top schools in quantitative/mathematical finance. I am sure that there should be lists/ratings like there are for mathematical universities - I've just haven't found them on the web. 
Finally, this question is not to build up the discussion. It asks for the direct, well-stated answer. It is related to the academic area of the quant-field. I ask it on exactly this site because here one can hope to receive a nice answer which will be non-subjective and useful rather than what I expect to receive on other sites.

The entire text of your question:

I am a PhD student in stochastic analysis/control and had a MSc degree in Financial Mathematics. Could you tell me what are the top quant institutes to do PostDoc in Europe and US?

How do you define "top"?
That's why it falls into the 'favorite' category here https://quant.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask

To prevent your question from being flagged and possibly removed, avoid asking subjective questions where …

every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”


This is, at best, a "list of X" question. Perhaps if you could clarify in very precise language what you mean by top and what metrics answerers could use to define that concept and provide answers that are more than opinions.

Thanks, I've edited it to make it precise.

ok, I edited it a bit more and reopened it. We'll see how it goes.

thank you for the help!
